# Functions in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON which contains function names:

```
{
 "login": "do_login",
 "logout": "do_logout"
}
```

Is it possible after parsing that JSON to call functions `do_login` and `do_logout`?

I mean this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse({"login": "do_login","logout": "do_logout"});
obj.login();
```

Comment: In this case you wouldn't need JSON parse. Where do you get this object from? Is it a string and therefor you want to parse it back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly but try this

```
window[obj.login]();
```

Comment: assumes the functions are present in the global scope. Worth checking so that you don't try to `call` undefined if the JSON source is untrusted.

Comment: No, there will be type error because `obj.login` isn't a function.

Comment: It's not calling `obj.login` as a function, it's calling a function which name is the string value of `obj.login` inside the window object. In case you want to call a method of another object just do `myInstance[obj.login]()`

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused about what JSON is.  JSON is a string that represents an object.  What you have above is known as an object literal.

A JSON string would look like this "{\"login\":\"do_login\",\"logout\":\"do_logout\"}"

This is a common mistake since both have a similar layout.  This is no accident.  When Crawford came up with JSON he modeled it on javascript object literals.

Functions are not converted to JSON strings, JSON.stringify will ignore them.

Example:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {
        console.log('bar');
    },
    something: 'something'

}

JSON.stringify(foo) // "{\"something\":\"something\"}"
```

I can run foo.bar() in my code, but this is not JSON it is a JS object.

Comment: Nice to see somebody distinguishing between JSON and JS objects, but I think the OP's code has the _name_ of a function in the object (whether or not what OP calls "JSON" actually is JSON) as a string and wants to use that name to call the function (which must be defined elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var obj = function(){};
obj.login = function(){
 //login code
};

obj["login"]();//call login function
```

Here is a better worded example:

```
var Functions = function(){};
Functions.do_login = function(){
 //login code
};
var callbacks = JSON.parse('{"login":"do_login","logout":"do_logout"}');
Functions[callbacks["login"]]();
```

See a working fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hvx7m/2/

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @Jan - You are wrong. The string from json could be the parameter used on `obj`. Perhaps the wording is confusing to you in this answer. For example, the OP wanted to call the function "do_login" then they could call it from where it was scoped. I was suggesting here to build the scope before hand instead of using a global scope.

Comment: You didn't explain that, and you use the same names as the OP but to do different things. And `obj["login"]` would not execute a function, just return it. Something like this: `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
var myFunc = {};
myFunc.do_login = function(){
 //login code
};
obj[jsonString.login]();` would make more sense.

Comment: You are correct about the requirement of the parenthesis, edited to change.